# Accessing instance from symbol class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a text field with the type "Input text" and put the instance name to *NameInput*. I have also created a MovieClip symbol which works like a button. Basically, I want to trace what text/input *NameInput* has from the button class.

trace(NameInput.x) does not work and shows the error "1120: Access of undefined property NameInput."

How can I access the instance *NameInput* from the button class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `trace(NameInput.x)`, ActionScript looks for an object *within* your button with that name, and doesn't find it. You might be able to try
    `var nameInput = MovieClip(this.parent).getChildByName('NameInput');`